# Dynamically populate pathForResource

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm having serious brain issues today. I am passing data into a `ViewController` from a `UITableView`. Basically what I want to achieve is dynamically populate the `pathForResource@"dynamicallypopulated"` with what ever is coming from the `UITableView` (it will then go on to get the txt file associated). When I step through the code the value is `NULL` even though it's set just above it and I can output it.

The code:

```
 NSString *location = self.animalTitle;

    NSLog(@"path : %@",animalTitle);
    NSLog(@"path : %@",location);

    //initWithFormat:@"Your favorite color is %@", favoriteColorTextField.text

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[location to be dynamic!!! what should I put here?] ofType:@"txt"];
```

Thanks in advance!

Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

Ug.

I worked it out. There was nothing wrong with the code. It had to do with the file I was bringing in which provided the content was cached and the project needed a good clean...Ironic really as that is what I do first. Nevertheless, below is the code completed and working.

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:animalTitle ofType:@"txt"];
```

Brian fart resolved.

Thanks!